# Hilbert's incidence axioms

Tags: geometry

How can I prove the following using only Hilbert's incidence axioms for geometry?

Given a finite set of distinct planes, there is a point not contained in any one of them.

If the set was of only two distinct planes, $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $, I would know that there is a point not lying in, for example, $ \alpha $. But how do I know it doesn't lie in $ \beta$? The eighth incidence axiom only seems to give me a second plane, how would I get a third?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it's impossible to prove it. Consider a tetrahedron (4 points, 6 lines and 4 planes), it satisfies all incidence axioms but there is no point not contained in a plane.